# Same database - different output from different clients

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, intellij-idea, sqlplus

I have a docker container with Oracle DB which I try to access from different clients with same credentials and its behaviour is quite strange.

I have set up connection in **IDEA** with following JDBC URL: **jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1526/XEPDB1**

Also I work with it via **Spring Data** framework in another container, url is **jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521/XEPDB1** (port is forwarded to outer world as 1526, container name is oracle)

And finally, I tried to access the db using **sqlplus from within db host**: **sqlplus LOGIN/PASSWORD@localhost:1521/XEPDB1**

All connections are successful, but simple inserts and selects for same table show that each client sees only it's own modifications. What is wrong? How do I share same table between clients?

Comment: Are you sure you're committing the data you've inserted?

Comment: @Mureinik thank you very much! I'll accept if you post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the connection strings, all the users are connected to the same database, so that isn't the issue.

The issue is probably that each user that modifies the data (e.g., inserts new rows), does so without committing, and thus this data is only available in their current session. Once they commit the data, it will be available to all the other sessions too.